# Laravel: how to access record by id in view

Tags: php, laravel-4

In my controller I return a view with a ?collection `$programs`? from an eloquent query to the view.

**Controller**

```
    $programs = ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today) 

    return View::make('admin/register_users/show', compact(programs));
```

I wan to do something like this without it running a new query from the view...

**VIEW**

```
{{$program->find(id)}}
```

I know that `$programs` is a dataset that already has the record, but I don't know the way to access the element by ID this way.

How do I do this?

(sorry, seems like an obviously searchable question but my search terms aren't comming up with the answer)

Comment: Where are you getting the ID from?

Comment: arbitrary id - i want to access a specific id that is determined dynamically based on what row is clicked.

Comment: Why not then just pass it along as a GET variable? Then you can use `ScheduledProgram::find($id);`. If you want it clickable and shown on the same page, you're going to have to use javascript/ajax, and basically do the same.

Comment: you mean as an accessor? https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: No, by using the primary key: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage

Answer (score 0):

in that case you need to make a @foreach in $programs to access the data. Like this:

```
 @foreach($programs as $key => $value)
    {{$value->id}}
 @endforeach
```

If the return is only one line you can do this:

```
{{$programs[0]->id}}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the one where `id=5` without iterating all of them?

Comment: If you want to show only one line, you need to treat it on your Controller.   
 `foreach($programs as $key => $value){   
    if($value->id == 5) $program_unic = $value;  
}

`

Answer (score 0):

1.You have to add the method get (converts the "dataset " in a Laravel collection) to iterate the collection.

```
$programs = ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today)
             ->get()
```

2.If you want to get a single record:

```
ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today)->where('id', 5)->get();
```